# Showing Div When Text Box Matches Criteria

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox, show

I need to show a div when a text box has a value of (as an example) "Hello", of course it does not really need "Hello" that's just an example. So, with JavaScript, I assume I can do this, but I am not very good with JavaScript and would like some help.

Comment: `if (myform.myinput.value=='hello') {...`. Google "javascript form", it's helpful : there are many tutorials for this kind of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Without further clarity on exactly *when* you want this to occur, I'm unable to provide a specific answer, but for guidance the following should suffice:

```
var stringToMatch = 'hello',
    input = document.getElementById('inputElementId'),
    div = document.getElementById('divId');

input.onkeyup = function(e){
    if (this.value == stringToMatch){
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
};​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DzSA7/1/).

In case you'd prefer case-insensitive matching:

```
var stringToMatch = 'hello',
    input = document.getElementById('inputElementId'),
    div = document.getElementById('divId');

input.onkeyup = function(e){
    if (this.value.toLowerCase() == stringToMatch.toLowerCase()){
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
};​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DzSA7/2/).

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`element.onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onkeyup).
- [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style).
- [`string.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response I am wanting it to be instant from when the last letter of "Hello" (the 'o') is entered I want the div to show.

Comment: Well, in that case the above code should work, though for some reason I used `textarea` instead of `div`...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/dvZHx/

```
<div id="div2show">Show me</div>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>​
```

```
input = document.getElementById('text'), div = document.getElementById('div2show');

input.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (this.value == 'hello') {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
};​
```